# Using pyside with QWebView and QUiLoader: what dependencies are needed

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qwebview

The following code works on one Ubuntu machine, but one a new one. I believe this is a dependency issue, but I have already installed all packages with *pyside* or *qt4* in their names.

I am loading a `ui` file like this:

```
loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader() 
window = loader.load(uifile)
```

The relevant portions of the `ui` file are:

```
<widget class="QWebView" name="mbody" native="true"/>
...
<customwidget>
 <class>QWebView</class>
 <extends>QWidget</extends>
 <header>QtWebKit/QWebView</header>
</customwidget>
```

This fails with the error `QFormBuilder was unable to create a custom widget of the class 'QWebView'; defaulting to base class 'QWidget'.`

*

I tried adding `loader.registerCustomWidget(QWebView)` just before loading but it made no difference.

The full code is actually [available online](https://github.com/luispedro/rbit/blob/master/gui/RBitMain.py) if you think it matters.

Comment: No, I never found the solution.

Comment: Why are you registering PySide.QtWebKit.QWebView as the custom class? Shouldn't you be using your own?

Comment: still no solution?